# Chrome / Mozilla - Mask html file name (index.html) to HomePage

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html pages prototype. If I open any `.html` file in browser, it shows `index.html`, `page1.html` etc at the brows...

What my boss wants is, she dont want clients to feel these are not .html pages. Instead it has to rename either `index.html` to `Index` or `HomePage`...

Please refer below image for clear idea...

I do know this can be done by JSP/PHP etc... But, these are all just static html pages and some times we will be sending all these html pages to client directly. In that case, we cannot ask client to install server... there is a tricky part :(

I know this is weird, but **Boss is always right** :)

[image]

> **OR**

[image]

Comment: It's not really weird - it's how many websites behave, including this one.  Either way, this is something you need to handle server side.  What do you use to serve your website (ie what webserver, do you use a dynamic language, or is it all static html as per your example)?

Comment: Hi **@James Thorpe**, thanks for your reply. These are all just static html pages and some times we will be sending all these html pages to client directly. In that case, we cannot ask client to install server... there is a tricky part :(

Comment: If I understand your question right, you can make a folder with `HomePage` name then place index.html into it, the run this url `/path/HomePages` if it didn't work , I think should say **Can't** do this without server side codes.

Comment: Thanks **@jiff**... but I have 250+ html pages... I dont think it is good idea to create 250 folders :(... Anyhow thanks for the tip